# Why does SHT21 sensor generate pulses on SDA line?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, i2c, pulse

I am interfacing a MSP432 microcontroller with a SHT21 sensor. The I2C bus contains only these two devices and has 2k2 pull-ups.

The problem is that the sensor continually generates impulses on SDA line and because of this I cannot communicate correctly with the sensor. I've tried changing the sensor with another one, but it behaves the same.

This is how the pulses look like:

[image]

The datasheet and Internet forums do not say anything about this behavior. It is weird that both sensors behaved the same. When I remove the sensor, the SDA line is OK.

The sensor is not PWM type because the frequency is much higher than that described in the datasheet.

[image]

**Has anybody encountered this? Could it be a hardware-related problem?**

Comment: What is the SCL line doing while this is happening?

Comment: It is high. Even if a I generate a start or stop, the impulses are still generated by the sensor.

Comment: What is the power supply voltage of the sensor? Is there a bulk capacitor close? This may be a sensor SHT21P with PWM output.

Comment: The power supply is 3.3V. There is a 100nF capacitor on the microcontroller board, but not on the sensor board which is connected to the first by 10 cm wires. I think you are right, it may be a SHT21P version (I didn't even knew that there is another version of the sensor). I ordered the SHT21 version from Farnell, but I wouldn't be surprised if they gave me the wrong chip (it wouldn't be the first time). I will verify and return with an update. Thank you!

Comment: @AltAir I does not seem to be PWM since the frequency is much higher than that described in the datasheet. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: [SHT21S](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1302072.pdf) is with SDM output.

Comment: @AltAir Thanks again! I just found out that I had a different sensor than expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is the problem. The marking on the sensor is S7WPH, which means it has SDM interface and is manufactured in 2017, according to the datasheet. I received a different sensor from Farnell than that which I ordered.